# jquery select elements by class using name from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to do somethings in jQuery to all the elements which match on a certain class name. The class name comes from a variable. How do I do the select using by class using my variable?

```
var x = $(this).attr('href').slice(1);
```

this will set `x` equal to the name of the `class` I want.

now I want to select all the elements with that class name

I try stuff like this but it doesn't work

```
$(.x.show().addClass('active').siblings().hide().removeClass('active');
```

basic basically I want affect all the elements with where `class = x`

Finally, instead of setting `x` to the class name, can I just get my `array` of classes in the first variable assignment?

i.e. instead of

```
var x = $(this).attr('href').slice(1);
```

can I do this [pseudo code]:

```
var x = classname is $(this).attr('href').slice(1);
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Selector is nothing more than just a string. So you could use

```
$('.' + classname)
```

where `classname` is a variable that holds particular class name

Comment: Thank you! that helped immensely. I'm just getting started with jQuery, but really like it.

Using this as part of a tabs system

`$('.' +     myelements).show().addClass('active').siblings().hide().removeClass('active');`

Answer (score 6):

try changing your code like this

```
$('.' + x).show().addClass('active').siblings().hide().removeClass('active');
```