# Accessing a class name that is stored in the Jquery variable

Tags: jquery, html, css

There are three pictures on the site.

```
<img src="images/kep1.jpg" class="kep1">
<img src="images/kep2.jpg" class="kep2">
<img src="images/kep4.jpg" class="kep4">
```

Click function to magnify one page at a time in the middle of the page page, but I'll store the necessary data in a variable.

```
var pos;
    var t;
    var h;
    var pic;
$("img").click(function(){
            pos = $(this).css("position");
            pic = $(this).attr("class");
            t = $(this).css("top");
            h = $(this).css("height");
            $(".szurkeDiv").show();
            $(this).animate(
                {
                    "position" : "fixed",
                    "top" : "50%",
                    "left" : "50%",
                    "margin-top" : "-300px",
                    "margin-left" : "-400px",
                    "width" : "800px",
                    "height" : "600px"
                }, 1000, function(){}
            );
        });
```

Then I want you to click on the image in the middle of the page to animate it back to its original location. I would like to access the PIC variable but not succeed.

```
$(pic).animate(
                {
                    "position" : pos,
                    "width" : "150px",
                    "margin-top" : "0px",
                    "margin-left" : "0px",
                    "left" : "5px",
                    "height" : h,
                    "top" : t
                }, 1000, function(){}
            );
```

How can I do this well, refer to the PIC variable?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery select elements by class using name from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293587/jquery-select-elements-by-class-using-name-from-variable)

Comment: __jQuery is not a language, it's a library for JavaScript.__ It doesn't do any magic, it's written in JavaScript code. You should learn the basics of JavaScript before trying to learn how to use any third-party library. I'm not trying to sound judgmental here, just save yourself some trouble and sit through a proper lesson.

Comment: I'm just learning this. This was the home lesson!
:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it with $('.' + pic) instead of $(pic).

See https://jsfiddle.net/g15v3c4z/

```
var pic = $('p').attr("class");

$('.' + pic).html('world!');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use plain CSS for the animation:

```js
var img = $("img")

img.on("click", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("zoom");
})
```

```css
img {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;

}

.zoom {
  transform:scale(2);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" alt="">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" alt="">

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" alt="">

</div>
```